# Can appDelegate use a function which is declared on a UIviewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

is it possible to call a function which is declared in a UIViewcontroller to use or pass a value
from APNs in the app delegate method

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary  *)userInfo {... }
```

Comment: Does the `appDelegate` have a reference of the `viewController`?

Comment: Yes, provided the view controller is loaded and the appDelegate has a pointer to it

Comment: posting a Local Notification (NSNotificationCenter) from the app delegate is probably the way to go, the View Controller can register for the notification and handle it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Any object can invoke methods on any other object.  But be careful.  Often, getting an hanging onto a reference to a view controller (except container view controllers and delegates) is engaging in an anti-pattern that will end in sadness.

For additional help.  Please post the app delegate code that initializes the pointer to the vc.